# How to detect code duplication among multiple python source files?

Tags: python, code-analysis, static-analysis, pylint, code-duplication

I have placed all python project sources in a single folder. Running the following `pylint` only seems to be looking and analyzing for duplicates within each source file and not across all which is what I intended:

```
pylint --disable=all --enable=duplicate-code /some/source/folder/
```

Is there a way to find code duplicates across many source files?

Comment: What if you concatenated all the sources into a single temporary file and ran `pylint` over that one file? Would that bring you a step closer?